# Doesn't display description from json file. Js funktion doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, django-views

I want to extract description for each field from json file. It is necessary for me that when the user clicks on a field, it displays a description of this field on the page.
First question: whether it correctly extracts all descriptions of all fields, since it seems to me that it extracts not quite correctly?
Second question: on the page write "Description not found" and the description does not display on the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z7kQ.png)

```
class PeerReviewView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
     def load_json_schema(self):
        with open('dataedit/static/peer_review/schema.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            json_schema = json.load(f)
        return(json_schema)`
 `    def get_all_field_descriptions(self, json_schema):
        field_descriptions = {}
        def extract_descriptions(properties, prefix=""):
            for field, value in properties.items():
                if "description" in value:
                    key = f"{prefix}.{field}" if prefix else field
                    field_descriptions[key] = value["description"]
                if "properties" in value:
                    new_prefix = f"{prefix}.{field}" if prefix else field
                    extract_descriptions(value["properties"], new_prefix)
        extract_descriptions(json_schema["properties"])
        return field_descriptions
 def get(self, request, schema, table):
        review_state = PeerReview.is_finished
        columns = get_column_description(schema, table)
        json_schema = self.load_json_schema()
        can_add = False
        table_obj = Table.load(schema, table)
        field_descriptions = self.get_all_field_descriptions(json_schema)
        print(field_descriptions)
        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
            level = request.user.get_table_permission_level(table_obj)
            can_add = level >= login_models.WRITE_PERM
        url_table_id = request.build_absolute_uri(
            reverse("view", kwargs={"schema": schema, "table": table})
        )
        metadata = self.sort_in_category(schema, table)
        context_meta = {"config": json.dumps(
            {"can_add": can_add,
             "url_peer_review": reverse(
                 "peer_review", kwargs={"schema": schema, "table": table}
             ),
             "url_table": reverse(
                 "view", kwargs={"schema": schema, "table": table}
             ),
             "table": table,
             }),
            "meta": metadata,
            "columns": json.dumps(columns),
            "json_schema": json_schema,
            "field_descriptions_json": json.dumps(field_descriptions),
        }
        return render(request, 'dataedit/opr_review.html', context=context_meta)
```

Is's part of json file:

```
   {"title": "OEM Creator - Generate metadata strings using OEMetadata v1.5",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Title",
            "description": "A human readable full title including author. Example: Example title for metadata example - Version 1.5.1"  },
        "language": {
            "description": "An array of languages used within the described data structures. Standard: IETF (BCP47)",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "title": "language",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "en-GB",
                    "en-US",
                    "de-DE",
                    "fr-FR",
                    "other"     ]    } },
        "subject": {
            "description": "Reference the topic of the resource in ontology terms",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "description": "The class label (name) of the ontology term.",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Name",
                        "format": "autocomplete",
                        "options": {
                            "autocomplete": {
                                "search": "search_name",
                                "getResultValue": "getResultValue_name",
                                "renderResult": "renderResult_name",
                                "autoSelect": true          }         }    },
                    "path": {
                        "description": "The URI of the class.",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Path",
                        "format": "uri"        }   },
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "title": "Subject"   },
            "title": "Subject"  },
        "publicationDate": {
            "description": "Date of publishing. Date Format is ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD). Example: 2019-02-06",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Publication date",
            "format": "date"   },
        "context": {
            "description": "An object that describes the general setting, environment, or project leading to the creation or maintenance of this dataset. In science this is can be the research project.",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "homepage": {
                    "description": "A URL of the project. Example: https://openenergy-platform.org/",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Homepage",
                    "format": "uri"    },
                "publisherLogo": {
                    "description": "A URL to the logo of the publishing agency of data. Example: https://reiner-lemoine-institut.de//wp-content/uploads/2015/09/rlilogo.png",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Publisher logo",
                    "format": "uri" }   },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "title": "Context" },
        "spatial": {
            "description": "Object. Contains name-value-pairs describing the spatial context of the contained data.",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "description": "In the case of data where the location can be described as a point. May come as coordinates, URI or addresses with street, house number and zip code. Example: 52.433509, 13.535855",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Location"   },
                "extent": {
                    "description": "Covered area. May be the name of a region, or the geometry of a bounding box. Example: Europe",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Extent"    },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "title": "Spatial" },
        "sources": {
            "description": "List of source objects. Each object has all name-value-pairs.",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "description": "Source object in list of source objects. Each object has all name-value-pairs.",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "description": "Free text description of the data set. Example: Scientific climate change report by the UN",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Description"   },
                    "path": {
                        "description": "URL to original source. Example: https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/02/ipcc_wg3_ar5_full.pdf",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Path",
                        "format": "uri"     },
                    "licenses": {
                        "description": "The license(s) under which the source(s) is/are provided. List of objects.",
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "description": "A license object under which the described source is provided. Each object has all name-value-pairs.",
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "description": "SPDX identifier: Example: ODbL-1.0",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "title": "Name"  },
                                "instruction": {
                                    "description": "Short description of rights and restrictions. Example: You are free to share and change, but you must attribute, and share derivations under the same license.",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "title": "Instruction"   }},
                            "title": "Licenses"   },
                        "title": "Licenses"      }   },
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "title": "Sources"   },
            "title": "Sources" },
        "licenses": {
            "description": "The license(s) under which the described package is provided. List of objects.",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "description": "A license object under which the described package is provided. Each object has all name-value-pairs.",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "description": "SPDX identifier. Example: ODbL-1.0",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Name"  },
                    "title": {
                        "description": "Official (human readable) title. Example: Open Data Commons Open Database License 1.0",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Title"  },
                    "attribution": {
                        "description": "Copyrightholder of the produced data set. Example: © Reiner Lemoine Institut",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Attribution"    }  },
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "title": "Licenses" },
            "title": "Licenses"   },
        "resources": {
            "description": "Resources, described as a list of data resource format objects.",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "description": "The data resource format describes a data resource as an individual file or table.",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "profile": {
                        "description": "A string identifying the profile of this descriptor as per the profiles specification. This information is retained in order to comply with the \"Tabular Data Package\" standard. If at all in doubt the value should read \"tabular-data-resource\". Example: tabular-data-resource",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Profile",
                        "default": "tabular-data-resource"  },
                    "name": {
                        "description": "A resource MUST contain a name unique to amongst all resources in this data package. To comply with the data package standard it must consist of only lowercase alphanumeric character plus \".\", \"-\" and \"_\". It may not start with a number. In a database this will be the name of the table within its containing schema. It would be usual for the name to correspond to the file name (minus the file-extension) of the data file the resource describes. Example: sandbox.example_table",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Name"   },
                    "schema": {
                        "description": "Object containing fields, primary key and for foreign keys. Describes the structure of the present data.",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "fields": {
                                "description": "List of field objects.",
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "description": "Field object. Every object describes a column and provides name, description, type and unit.",
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "name": {
                                            "description": "Name string unique within its scope. Example: year",
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "title": "Name"        },
                                        "description": {
                                            "description": "Free-text describing the field. Example: Reference year for which the data were collected.",
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "title": "Description"      },
                                        "isAbout": {
                                            "description": "Ontology URI to describe the column header",
                                            "type": "array",
                                            "items": {
                                                "type": "object",
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "name": {
                                                        "description": "Name of the Dataset",
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "title": "Name",
                                                        "format": "autocomplete",
                                                        "options": {
                                                            "autocomplete": {
                                                                "search": "search_name",
                                                                "getResultValue": "getResultValue_name",
                                                                "renderResult": "renderResult_name",
                                                                "autoSelect": true     }         }      },
                                                    "path": {
                                                        "description": "Path to the OEO (URL)",
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "title": "Path",
                                                        "format": "uri"     }              },
                                                "additionalProperties": false,
                                                "title": "Is About"          },
                                            "title": "Is About"      },
                                        "valueReference": {
                                            "description": "Ontology URI for an extended description of the values in the column",
                                            "type": "array",
                                            "items": {
                                                "type": "object",
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "description": "The value this reference is assinged to.",
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "title": "Value"    },
                                                    "name": {
                                                        "description": "Full name of the value",
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "title": "Name",
                                                        "format": "autocomplete",
                                                        "options": {
                                                            "autocomplete": {
                                                                "search": "search_name",
                                                                "getResultValue": "getResultValue_name",
                                                                "renderResult": "renderResult_name",
                                                                "autoSelect": true        }     }      },
```

I made a function to extract all fields from a json file:

```
def get_all_field_descriptions(self, json_schema):
        field_descriptions = {}
        def extract_descriptions(properties, prefix=""):
            for field, value in properties.items():
                if "description" in value:
                    key = f"{prefix}.{field}" if prefix else field
                    field_descriptions[key] = value["description"]
                if "properties" in value:
                    new_prefix = f"{prefix}.{field}" if prefix else field
                    extract_descriptions(value["properties"], new_prefix)
        extract_descriptions(json_schema["properties"])
        return field_descriptions
```

Further, in the js file, the function is called when the user clicks on the field, and if there is such a field of such a category in the get_all_field_descriptions function, the description of this field is displayed on the page

```
function click_field(fieldKey, fieldValue, category) {
    selectedField = fieldKey;
    selectedFieldValue = fieldValue;
    selectedCategory = category;
    const selectedName = document.querySelector("#review-field-name");
    selectedName.textContent = fieldKey + " " + fieldValue;
    const fieldDescriptionsElement = document.getElementById("field-descriptions");
    console.log("Field descriptions data:", fieldDescriptionsData);

    const fieldKeyWithCategory = category + '.' + fieldKey;
    if (fieldDescriptionsData[fieldKeyWithCategory]) {
        fieldDescriptionsElement.textContent = fieldDescriptionsData[fieldKeyWithCategory];
    } else {
        fieldDescriptionsElement.textContent = "Описание не найдено";
    }
    console.log("Category:", category, "Field key:", fieldKey, "Data:",     fieldDescriptionsData[fieldKeyWithCategory]);
    }
```

Next, in the html for each category, I make a call to the click_field () function and output on the description page

```
 <script>
  const fieldDescriptionsData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("field-descriptions-      json").textContent);
    </script>`
`    <div id="field-descriptions-json" style="display: none;">
     {{ field_descriptions_json }}</div>
    <div id="field-descriptions"></div>`
It's for example for one category
`    <p>SPATIAL</p>
            {% for item in meta.spatial %}<div id="field_{{item.field}}" class="field"      onclick="click_field('{{item.field}}', '{{ item.value }}', 'spatial');">
                <p>{{item.field}}:  {{ item.value }} </p></div>  {% endfor %}
```

if anyone knows what the problem is please tell me

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)